# Qual a melhor forma de guardar dados temporarios em android?

Tags: android

Estou usando da seguinte forma:

```
val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

val editor = prefs.edit()
editor.putString(Constants.VENDOR_UPDATE_AT, update_date)
editor.commit()
```

e buscando

```
var update_date = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(Constants.VENDOR_UPDATE_AT, "")
```

Lembrando que tenho o contexto mas não estou em uma *activity*.

Comment: O que considera como "dados temporários"?

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` não foi feito para guardar dados temporários, e sim configurações do aplicativo como descrito na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings?hl=pt-br) do android, se você deseja armazenar dados temporários você deveria armazenar em [cache](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteCacheFileInternal), mas se você deseja salvar esses dados para quando a aplicação for ficar em segundo plano ou algo do tipo, deveria usar onSaveInstanceState para armazenar esses dados temporariamente, segue o exemplo da [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#lc) do android:

```
TextView mTextView;

// some transient state for the activity instance
String mGameState;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // call the super class onCreate to complete the creation of activity like
    // the view hierarchy
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // recovering the instance state
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mGameState = savedInstanceState.getString(GAME_STATE_KEY);
    }

    // set the user interface layout for this activity
    // the layout file is defined in the project res/layout/main_activity.xml file
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    // initialize member TextView so we can manipulate it later
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
}

// This callback is called only when there is a saved instance that is previously saved by using
// onSaveInstanceState(). We restore some state in onCreate(), while we can optionally restore
// other state here, possibly usable after onStart() has completed.
// The savedInstanceState Bundle is same as the one used in onCreate().
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(TEXT_VIEW_KEY));
}

// invoked when the activity may be temporarily destroyed, save the instance state here
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(GAME_STATE_KEY, mGameState);
    outState.putString(TEXT_VIEW_KEY, mTextView.getText());

    // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, obrigado pela explicação! Vou fazer dessa forma!